# Unfortunately MySQL Slow Query Log does not log replication queries

Tags: mysql

Is the statement from the head line TRUE ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before MySQL 5.1.45: **true**

since MySQL 5.1.45 : **false**

> By default, a replication slave does not write replicated queries to
>   the slow query log. To change this, use the
>   --log-slow-slave-statements server option.

[MySQL Manual Page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html)

Comment: Thanks Justin T... You posted one more important server variable "log-slow-slave-statements"